# (c#)How to implement a high performance duplicate check?

Tags: c#, msmq

i want to find out a high performance duplicate check way. does anybody can help me ?
i implement the check as the below, but now, i hope the speed can catch up sending message into a queue(MSMQ), so the old way is not fit with us .

my old way:

1. create a simple table(oracle db)
2. create PK on the column which i want to do the duplicate checking.

firstly, i will insert a record with try-catch into the table.

```
if(insert succeed)
{
not duplicate
}
else
{
duplicate
}
```

PS:
the messages need to check is very large, so i can't record them into the memory.

Comment: what is the type of data you want to check? int, string?

Comment: Do you have a huge number of messages that need to be checked, or are the messages themselves very large?  Just asking as the latter might not preclude in-memory checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like 
[managedesent](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/)

Check out the persistent dictionary implementation.